# python - how do I specify allowed patterns for **kwargs?

Tags: python

As the title suggests, I want to accept if the arguments fit a certain pattern, otherwise return an error message. *The order of arguments doesn't matter, as I am using (forcing to use) keyword arguments anyway.*

for example, let's say I have the following patterns:

- `hex_list`
- `int_list`
- `int_list, size`
- `hex_list, size`
- `from_file`

※ `size`, `hex_list`, `int_list`, and `from_file` are keyword arguments.
※ I have to use **only one** of the above patterns for the arguments I will send.
※ e.g. `from_file, size` **is not** allowed!
※ Normally there are more arguments, but I also reduced the number of arguments to reduce confusion.

As you can see most use only one argument but I still have some argument patterns that use multiple (2) arguments.

for use case:

```py
class Calculator:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if args:                                                     
      raise ValueError("Calculator can only be called with keyword arguments")
    
    allowed_keys = "size", "hex_list", "int_list", "from_file"
    
    for keyword in kwargs.keys():                               
      if keyword not in allowed_keys:                         
        raise ValueError("wrong keyword!")

    hex_list = kwargs.get("hex_list")
    int_list = kwargs.get("int_list")
    from_file = kwargs.get("from_file")
    size = kwargs.get("size")
    
    if from_file:
      if hex_list or int_list or size:
        raise ValueError("When 'from_file' is specified, you cannot give any other args")
      # do stuff
    elif hex_list:
      if int_list or from_file:
        raise ValueError("When 'hex_list' is specified, you can only give a value to the 'size' arg")
      # do stuff
    elif int_list:
      if hex_list or from_file:
        raise ValueError("When 'int_list' is specified, you can only give a value to the 'size' arg")
      # do stuff
    else:
      raise ValueError("wrong arg(s)")     

    # do more stuff ...
```

It seems okay for this specific example, but as I mentioned above I normally have a lot more arguments. Therefore, the amount of `or` operator I will write increases and it becomes difficult to read, like:

```py
if from_file:
  if hex_list or int_list or size or from_bits or byte_list or from_string or etc.:
```

That's why I wanted to create a specific list of patterns and follow it.
Is this okay to do this way? If it is why? *I mean doesn't this look like spaghetti code?*

And once again, how can I specify the patterns for **kwargs?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of possibilities here - you could do something like this

```
    allowed_keys = (
        {"hex_list", "size"},
        {"int_list", "size"}, 
        {"hex_list"},
        {"int_list"},
        {"from_file"},
    )
                       
    if set(kwargs.keys()) not in allowed_keys:                         
        raise ValueError("wrong keyword!")
```

Essentially comparing the list of arguments as one instead of individually, and using sets to ignore order.

Comment: I don't need the for loop in this case, do I?

Comment: Nope, that can go as you can equate entire sets